# Changing color between polygon gaps (QGIS 2.18.3)

Tags: qgis, polygon

[image]

Trying to figure out how to solve this. I'd like to change all of the white area some other color. Looking at the space spaces closely shows an optical illusion going on.

Anyone know how to change the white areas any other color?

Comment: _Wow I can see grey circles_...anyway, you could change the canvas colour from white to another from `Settings > Options > Canvas & Legend`. Or create a new layer with a polygon which covers all your smaller polygons, give this a colour and make sure you set the rendering order from the `Layer Order Panel` so that the layer with the single polygon is rendered below your other layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very quick and dirty way to do it is by creating a new layer (maybe just a scratch layer) with a polygon that spans all the other polygons then using some sort of clip or cut function to cut out where the small polygons are, then the big polygon would only span the "white" areas in your map and you could just color it whatever color :-)

**EDIT**:
Just looked more in to this, use the Difference function under Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools,

results:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If it is the canvas background that you want changing then head to 'Settings  >  Canvas & Legend'.  Under 'default map appearance' you can change the background colour to anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

1. Duplicate the layer.
2. Drag that new layer under the other layer.
3. Properties -> Style -> Inverted Polygons
4. In same window, select Single symbol and change the color to whatever.
5. APPLY, OK.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgHsgybLexg